# Word for the people whom you inspire

Tags: single-word-requests

People who are inspired by me might say "Imray is my inspiration".

But what word can I use to describe the people whom I inspire?

Comment: [*disciples?, acolytes?, fans?, devotees?, evangelists?*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/acolyte)

Comment: The inspired. Inspirees.

Comment: Perhaps *The inspired*?

Answer (score 1):

"**enthusiast**", which originally means "a person inspired by god", connotates "a person who is inspired by a cause or a person" in current English vernacular, thanks to semantic change. Though it mainly suggests an intense interest in something.

from **[vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/enthusiast)**:

> Enthusiast comes from the Greek **enthousiastēs**, meaning "person inspired by a god." While it doesn't retain those same religious connotations today, an enthusiast is someone **who is inspired by a cause or person**.
>
> A candidate running for office will have a group of enthusiasts working doggedly on his campaign.
>
> Often your mother is your biggest enthusiast or supporter.
>
> Non-profit organizations are always looking for enthusiasts who can make donations and become patrons of their organization.

Comment: just remember, *enthusiast* (like *gymnast*) rhymes with *forecast* and *iconoclast* and not with *breakfast* and *ballast*.

Comment: @nohat: But Merriam-Webster lists both pronunciations for both *enthusiast* and *gymnast*? (I'm new to this site, is M-W not accepted here?)

Comment: @nohat: Not in my accent it doesn't. My *enthusiast* and *iconoclast* end with a short "a" as it ***cat***, but my *forecast* has the long version as in ***cart***. That's because I'm *Southern English*. Northerers are different, and they don't always reduce the final vowel of *breakfast, ballast* to a neutral schwa as much as Southerners either.

Answer (score 1):

If someone says they are inspired by you, it doesn't necessarily mean they think of you as a role model, or even the person who *most* inspires them. It could easily mean you give them impetus to act (or not to act) a certain way. Unless these people are hanging on your every word, I wouldn't settle on any word suggesting a posse of fans. (If, on the other hand, they hang on your every word, and there's more than one of them, "stalkers" might work very well.)

Re-think the way they might mean "inspiration" and, with both positive and negative connotations in mind, assume you serve in some way as their **muse.** These people one inspires could then be called "**the bemused,**" as happens often in a classroom (or "**the unamused,**" as happens often in political uprisings.)

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable phrase would be "the inspired".